# About Struts2 Email Validator

Tags: regex, email, struts2, pattern-matching, validation

Struts2 have a perfect email validator. Its regex for single email address is below:

```
\\b(^[_A-Za-z0-9-](\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-])*@([A-Za-z0-9-])+((\\.com)|(\\.net)|(\\.org)|(\\.info)|(\\.edu)|(\\.mil)|(\\.gov)|(\\.biz)|(\\.ws)|(\\.us)|(\\.tv)|(\\.cc)|(\\.aero)|(\\.arpa)|(\\.coop)|(\\.int)|(\\.jobs)|(\\.museum)|(\\.name)|(\\.pro)|(\\.travel)|(\\.nato)|(\\..{2,3})|(\\..{2,3}\\..{2,3}))$)\\b
```

It is too long because of validating TLDs. But just look at start and end of it.

My question is about wrapping \\b. What does mean putting \\b in start and end of regex (even before ^ and after $)?

Comment: It is not at all "perfect", it disallows e.g. plus and equals signs in the local part, and disallows subdomains in the domain part (the CCTLD expression which was apparently tucked on as an afterthought accidentally remedies this somewhat, but it's still wrong).

Comment: OK. But this is not the point.

Comment: Hmm, the regex they are actually using is better.  The doc string is apparently out of date.  http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/struts/struts2/trunk/xwork-core/src/main/java/com/opensymphony/xwork2/validator/validators/EmailValidator.java?view=markup

Comment: Yeah, they seem spurious considering there's already `^/$`.

Answer (score 1):

This is about **Word Boundaries**:

The metacharacter \b is an anchor like the caret and the dollar sign. It matches at a position that is called a "word boundary". This match is zero-length.

There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:

- ***Before the first character*** in the string, if the first character is a word character.
- ***After the last character*** in the string, if the last character is a word character.
- Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Simply put: \b allows you to perform a "whole words only" search using a regular expression in the form of \bword\b. *A "word character" is a character that can be used to form words.* All characters that are not "word characters" are "non-word characters".

You can read more here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Answer (score 0):

They appear to be superfluous, perhaps remnants of an earlier version of the regex.